# How is kLAErrorPasscodeNotSet triggered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-id

I tried removing all fingerprints, disabling the passcode, both at the same time, but all i get is kLAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled
Can somebody explain this to me, please?

Comment: What LA policy are you using?

Comment: @Paulw11 LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics

Comment: Try `kLAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthentication`. You have requested biometrics, so it is telling you that biometrics aren't available.

Comment: @Paulw11 what you're telling me is that, while using that policy, kLAErrorPasscodeNotSet won't trigger at all in any case?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. You have asked for biometrics, and biometrics aren't available. It doesn't even get as far as considering whether a passcode is available.